# Handling token timeout using providers in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic 2 app with two providers, one related with OAuth authentication, and another with App services. When the app token expires, App service calls will return 401 errors

I would like a behavior where 401 errors are handled globally such that the OAuth provider will call the refresh token endpoint and update the token transparently

To achieve the above, I cannot directly handle errors in the App provider invoking the OAuth provider. I was thinking to override [ErrorHandler](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/ErrorHandler-class.html) class to handle 401 calls by invoking the OAuth provider and updating the local app token variables

Is that an architecturally sound decision? Would there be a preferred approach to implement the above?